# How can i have 2 classes reference the same instance of a class

Tags: python

I have class A class B and class C.

class A and B can affect class C. so they need to refer to the same instance of the class.

```
#a.py
from C import C
Cinstance = C()
Cinstance.add()


#b.py
class b(object)
#i need to refer to 'cinstance' here to control the same instance of the class

#C.py
class C(object)
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1

    def add(self):
        self.a += 1
        print a
```

How do i need to import and instanciate the classes for it to work this way? I am new to programming and still learning so things that are obvious are still a little difficult for me right now.

Comment: Keep in mind that Python is a case-sensitive language, so `Cinstance` is not `cinstance`. Also, you describe `a` as a class, but in your code it's a module.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,cInst):
        self.c = cInst

class B:
    def __init__(self,cInst):
        self.c = cInst

cInst = C()

a = A(cInst)
b = B(cInst)
```

something like that maybe

Answer (score 2):

based on what you have there I think the easiest thing would be to import `Cinstance` from module `a`.

```
from a import Cinstance
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an instance of A and B to your `C.__init__` method and save them as attributes of C.

I'm on my phone, so the code below isn't tested

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

>>> c = C(A(), B())
```